# What to do with an overwritten question with an open bounty?

Tags: discussion, editing, site-policies, specific-question, bounty

I'm referring to [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/370452/87579), which previously was asking "*How can I execute at a chest with a specific pattern of certain items?*"
Several edits have occured, also because OP was complaining about the downvotes.

This part is the most confusing to me:

> Ignore any other replies or comments. I had to ask here because I couldn't ask new questions.

Now we have a new question with an open bounty, and a post answering the previous question.
What should we do?

Comment: That's... one way to try and dodge an automated question ban.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have removed the bounty and rolled back the edit. In the future, if this comes up again, feel free to raise a custom moderator flag, since moderators have the ability to remove a bounty, refunding the reputation spent.